# How to do Type erasure in Swift using if-let?

Tags: swift

I see many articles on type-erasure. But most of their examples focus on putting different types into an array.

Is there any way I can get this code to work?

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype Data
    func printThis(value: Data)
}
class B {

}

let x = B()
if let y = x as? A {  // I get error on this line
    // Do nothing
}
```

Xcode error states 
`Protocol 'A' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

This example code is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: You need to also specify `Data` type during that cast and you can specify that only on concrete types.

Comment: @Sulthan how do I do that?

Comment: Since Swift doesn't have generalized existentials yet, you can't do this. Hopefully this will change in a future version of Swift.

Comment: wow.. thanks then. There are no work arounds either?

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile Nope. Note that your case has no practical usage. You wouldn't be able to call `printThis` with a specific type.

Comment: Here is a video that explains things pretty well. It's a bit old, so the syntax is not Swift 4, but you'll still get the gist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWoNjiSPqI8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Swift 4, protocols that have associated type requirements can *only* be used as generic constraints in function declarations, as in:

```
func foo<T: A>(t: T) where A.Data: Whatever { ... }
```

Unless you remove the associated type from the protocol, you cannot just type variables to it; you can *only* use it to define a generic type.

If Swift ever gains the ability to have generalized existentials in the future, then this may change. But for the time being, this just isn't possible in Swift.